# Load Text File Into Table Widget in Qt

Tags: qt, parsing, user-interface, text, stream

If I load a text file into a QTextStream, how would I then populate a TableWidget with its data? The text file is tab delimited. Here is what I have so far:

```
void MainWindow::startParsing()
{
            QStringList stringList;

            int countRows;

             QTextStream in(&textFile);
             QString line;
             if (textFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
             {
             do
             {
                 line = in.readLine();
                 stringList << line.split("\t", QString::SkipEmptyParts);
             }
             while (!in.atEnd());
             }

             QSet<QString> set = stringList.toSet();
             foreach (const QString &value, set)
                 qDebug() << value;


            countRows = stringList.count();

            //--- define the table's shape ---
            ui->tableWidget_inputPreview->setRowCount(countRows);
            ui->tableWidget_inputPreview->setColumnCount(6);

            //--- create the horizontal (column) headers ---
            QStringList horzHeaders;
            horzHeaders << "HostName" << "Host IP" << "Area" << "Host Interface"
                        << "Router to Ext Network" << "Ext Routes";
            ui->tableWidget_inputPreview->setHorizontalHeaderLabels( horzHeaders );

            //--- create the vertical (row) headers ---
            QStringList vertHeaders;
            ui->tableWidget_inputPreview->setVerticalHeaderLabels( vertHeaders );

            //--- populate the table widget with data from txt file ---

            // TODO: insert data into table
}
```

Here is a sample of the text file that I'm working with:

```
#TEST 1                 
#HostName   HostIP  Area    Host Interface  Router to Ext NW    Number of Ext Routes
test1   9.1.1.1 0.0.0.0         
OMG_LOL_101 128.12.101.2    0.0.0.0         
OMG_LOL_102 128.12.102.9    0.0.0.0 128.112.102.9   128.112.102.10  100
WTF_BBQ_149 128.20.180.2    0.0.0.0                 

#HITL 2                 
#HostName   HostIP  Area    Host Interface  Router to Ext NW    Number of Ext Routes
test2   9.1.1.2 0.0.0.0         
WTF_BBQ_111 128.15.110.2    0.0.0.0         
WTF_BBQ_112 128.15.111.2    0.0.0.0         
WTF_BBQ_113 128.15.112.2    0.0.0.0 128.115.112.9   128.115.112.10  100
```

Comment: What does `process_line(line)` do?  Where are you storing all the individual QStrings from the text file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
QTextStream in(&file);
QList< QStringList > lists;
QString line;
do {
    line = in.readLine();
    lists << line.split("\t");
} while (!line.isNull())

// Set the table size (assuming the rows are all the same length).
tableWidget.setRowCount( lists.size() );
tableWidget.setColumnCount( lists[0].size() );

for ( int row = 0; row < lists.size(); ++row ) {
    for ( int column = 0; column < lists[row].size(); ++column ) {
        tableWidget.setItem(row, column, new QTableWidgetItem(lists[row][column]));
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if "skipEmptyParts" should be passed to split. As it is tab delimed, then empty column should be left empty, not skipped

Comment: I am struggling with the part where I need to loop through the text entries to insert them into the table. It appears that one must enter the setRowCount and setColumnCount prior to inserting any data. What would the proper way be to do this for the entire text file that I'm parsing?

Comment: You need to parse the file first to see how big the table needs to be.

Comment: I am trying to use the setItem function of tableWidget from your example, but nothing is being inserted into the table.

Comment: I am not sure how to place the data from each text file into the appropriate column. I figure that I need to call setItem and loop through all the rows of that column, then call setItem again and do the same for all subsequent columns. I am struggling to figure out how to select each column's data right now. One thing that I tried which is not giving me the correct results was the following:        foreach (const QString &value, stringList)
        ui->tableWidget_inputPreview->setItem(row, col, new QTableWidgetItem(value));

Comment: It's hard to be specific without knowing how you are storing your data. If you are reading the file line by line, it's pretty unlikely that it would be easier inputting the data by columns, instead of row by row.  Also in the little you gave above - how are incrementing the rows/columns?

Comment: I updated my code example now I know what is being read (though I'm assuming you want it laid out like in the original file, correct me if I'm wrong).  And @KamilKlimek was absolutely right.

Comment: It worked! The way you insert data into a QTableWidget makes a lot more sense to me now. Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad you got it working.  Qt's model-view-(delegate) pattern is tough to get your head around, but it's very powerful and adaptable once you have.